# Difference between (Type) and Type

Tags: swift, swift2

Currently, I'm writing a class and protocol named `Control` and `Controllable`.

`Control` must conform to `Controllable`.

`Control` will have an array of other `Controllable`s as a stack. Every time before adding `Controllable` to the stack, I should check whether the stack contains that element. If yes, move the element to the top of stack.

Okay. 
VERSION_1:

```
import Foundation

protocol Controllable: Equatable {
}

func ==<T: Controllable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return ObjectIdentifier(lhs).uintValue == ObjectIdentifier(rhs).uintValue
}


class Control: Controllable {
    static var mainControl = Control()

    private init() {

    }

    private var stack: [Controllable] = []

    func addToStack(controllable: Controllable) {

    }
}
```

There is an error (Xcode 7.3):

```
return ObjectIdentifier(lhs).uintValue == ObjectIdentifier(rhs).uintValue
```

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'ObjectIdentifier' with an argument list of type '(T)'

**QUESTION 1:** Why? How can I construct `ObjectIdentifier` from `lhs` and `rhs`?

---

VERSION_2:

```
import Foundation

protocol Controllable {
}

class Control: Controllable {
    static var mainControl = Control()

    private init() {

    }

    private var stack: [Controllable] = []

    func addToStack(controllable: Controllable) {
        stack.contains({ element in
            return ObjectIdentifier(element).uintValue == ObjectIdentifier(controllable).uintValue
        })
    }
}
```

There is an error (, again):

```
return ObjectIdentifier(element).uintValue == ObjectIdentifier(controllable).uintValue
```

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'ObjectIdentifier' with an argument list of type '((Controllable))'

**QUESTION 2:** Is `(Controllable)` tuple? How should I extract `Controllable` from the tuple?

---

<sub>Sorry for my English</sub>

Comment: It looks like you want to restrict `Controllable` only to classes and then use `===`? Anyway, in the end you will have to declare your array as a concrete type, not a protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectIdentifier only works on objects and metatypes as argument in the constructor.

Types that conforms to Controllable are not conforming to the type constraint in the ObjectIdentifier constructor.

```
init(_ x: AnyObject)
init(_ x: Any.Type)
```

see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_ObjectIdentifier_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structctr/ObjectIdentifier/s:FVs16ObjectIdentifiercFPs9AnyObject_S_).

You want to give the ObjectIdentifier the metatype of a type, like String.self.
Or you want to give the ObjectIdentifier an object, like "hello". You could add the object constraint to the protocol like this:

```
import Foundation

protocol Controllable: Equatable, AnyObject {
}

func ==<T: Controllable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return ObjectIdentifier(lhs).uintValue == ObjectIdentifier(rhs).uintValue
}
```